# how can i handle the fragment1 onclick perform in fragment2?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am develop the app using the fragments and i am facing one fragment1 adding to the another fragment2
fragment1 onclicks performing fragment2 .I didn't findout the solution for that. please guide anyone know

I am using the following code to add the fragment

```
    Fragment2 fragment2=new Fragment2();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.container,fragment2);
    ft.hide(new Fragment1());
    ft.addToBackStack(Fragment1.class.getName());
    ft.commit();
```

The above to use adding onefragment1 adding to fragment2.Fragment1 onclicks perform to fragment2 . i didn't findout mistake.
please guide me anyone know .Advance thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

nested Fragments are not recommended and for adding a fragment to a container from another Fragment use the parent Activity to do so , you can define a function inside Parent Activity which replace current Fragment with your second Fragment and call it from your first.

Comment: but my requirement is adding the fragment and previous state   maintaining the fragment1 back to fragment2

Answer (score 1):

Adding a fragment to another fragment is the concept of nested fragments and not recommended. You should replace the fragment instead of adding. Use the following:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment2();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack("fragment").replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions i am using the backbutton i am  following method is  getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack() showing this error